# Why is the same CURL code failing on one server and yet works on the other one?

Tags: php, apache, curl, stream

The code attempts to grab a test page for example Yahoo.com in this case. I am outputting the var_dump

http://jinimatics.com/test.php  (this works)

http://jinimetrix.com/test.php (this does not)

(Curl is installed on both servers along with fairy recent Lamp Stack)

Comment: Also post errors if any. Depending on your server configuration errors may be silently written to a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare whats installed and version differences.

Comment: Server API  is CGI in one and "Apache 2.0 handler" in another.

Answer (score 0):

check your server settings with `phpinfo();`

then you can change settings in php.ini